# Kubernetes pod stuck in waiting state

Tags: kubernetes

Trying to start this pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: tinyproxy
spec:
  containers:
    - name: master
      image: asdrepo.isus.emc.com:8091/francisbesset/tinyproxy
      env:
        - name: MASTER
          value: "true"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "0.1"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tinyproxy-data
          name: data
  volumes:
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
```

This gets stuck in pending state. I looked in the troubleshooting guide, but this pod does not seem to have any events

```
$ kubectl describe pods tinyproxy
Name:       tinyproxy
Namespace:  default
Node:       /
Labels:     name=tinyproxy
Status:     Pending
IP:
Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  master:
    Image:  asdrepo.isus.emc.com:8091/francisbesset/tinyproxy
    Port:   6379/TCP
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:  Guaranteed
      memory:   BestEffort
    Limits:
      cpu:  100m
    Requests:
      cpu:  100m
    Environment Variables:
      MASTER:   true
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:   EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
No events.
```

Also

```
$ kubectl get events
FIRSTSEEN   LASTSEEN   COUNT     NAME                                                    KIND      SUBOBJECT   TYPE      REASON                  SOURCE                                                               MESSAGE
13m         13m        1         10.0.0.5                                                Node                  Normal    Starting                {kubelet 10.0.0.5}                                                   Starting kubelet.
13m         13m        2         10.0.0.5                                                Node                  Warning   MissingClusterDNS       {kubelet 10.0.0.5}                                                   kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. pod: "kube-proxy-10.0.0.5_kube-system(9fa6e0ea64b9f19ad6996367402408eb)". Falling back to DNSDefault policy.
13m         13m        1         10.0.0.5                                                Node                  Normal    NodeHasSufficientDisk   {kubelet 10.0.0.5}                                                   Node 10.0.0.5 status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
13m         13m        1         10.0.0.5                                                Node                  Normal    Starting                {kubelet 10.0.0.5}                                                   Starting kubelet.
13m         13m        1         10.0.0.5                                                Node                  Normal    NodeHasSufficientDisk   {kubelet 10.0.0.5}                                                   Node 10.0.0.5 status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
13m         13m        1         k8-dvawxybzux-0-a7m3diiryehx-kube-minion-itahxn4icom6   Node                  Normal    Starting                {kube-proxy k8-dvawxybzux-0-a7m3diiryehx-kube-minion-itahxn4icom6}   Starting kube-proxy.
```

The proxy does seem to be running and is not restarting

```
bash-4.3# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d6dd779b301f        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.2.0   "/hyperkube proxy --m"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes                           k8s_kube-proxy.d87e83d4_kube-proxy-10.0.0.5_kube-system_9fa6e0ea64b9f19ad6996367402408eb_caae92ac
8191770f15d9        gcr.io/google_containers/pause:2.0          "/pause"                 15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes                           k8s_POD.6059dfa2_kube-proxy-10.0.0.5_kube-system_9fa6e0ea64b9f19ad6996367402408eb_e4da5a30
```

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the scheduler service did not start (this is in an openstack VM). All services were supposed to be configured and started automatically. This worked after I started the service manually.