# spark driver pod stuck in Waiting: PodInitializing state in Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am running Spark 2.3 job on kubernetes cluster

*kubectl version*

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.3", GitCommit:"d2835416544f298c919e2ead3be3d0864b52323b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-02-09T21:51:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.3", GitCommit:"f0efb3cb883751c5ffdbe6d515f3cb4fbe7b7acd", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-11-08T18:27:48Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

when I ran spark submit on k8s master the driver pod is stuck in Waiting: PodInitializing state.

This is happening if I submit the jobs almost parallel i.e. submit 5 jobs one after the other.

I tried *kubectl describe node* on the node where the driver pod is running this is what I got ,I do see there is over-commit on resources but I expected kubernetes scheduler not to schedule if resources in node are *over-committed* or node is in *Not Ready* state, in this case node is in *Ready State* but I observe same behavior if node is in *Not Ready* state.

```
Name:               **********
Roles:              worker
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=****
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=true
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
Taints:             <none>
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 31 Jul 2018 09:59:24 -0400
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  OutOfDisk        False   Tue, 14 Aug 2018 09:31:20 -0400   Tue, 31 Jul 2018 09:59:24 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure   False   Tue, 14 Aug 2018 09:31:20 -0400   Tue, 31 Jul 2018 09:59:24 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Tue, 14 Aug 2018 09:31:20 -0400   Tue, 31 Jul 2018 09:59:24 -0400   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  Ready            True    Tue, 14 Aug 2018 09:31:20 -0400   Sat, 11 Aug 2018 00:41:27 -0400   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  *****
  Hostname:    ******
Capacity:
 cpu:     16
 memory:  125827288Ki
 pods:    110
Allocatable:
 cpu:     16
 memory:  125724888Ki
 pods:    110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 *************
 System UUID:                **************
 Boot ID:                    1493028d-0a80-4f2f-b0f1-48d9b8910e9f
 Kernel Version:             4.4.0-1062-aws
 OS Image:                   Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://Unknown
 Kubelet Version:            v1.8.3
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.8.3
PodCIDR:                     ******
ExternalID:                  **************
Non-terminated Pods:         (11 in total)

  Namespace                  Name                                                            CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ---------                  ----                                                            ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  kube-system                calico-node-gj5mb                                               250m (1%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                kube-proxy-****************************************             100m (0%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-9cntq                       100m (0%)     200m (1%)   30Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)
  logging                    elasticsearch-elasticsearch-data-69df997486-gqcwg               400m (2%)     1 (6%)      8Gi (6%)         16Gi (13%)
  logging                    fluentd-fluentd-elasticsearch-tj7nd                             200m (1%)     0 (0%)      612Mi (0%)       0 (0%)
  rook                       rook-agent-6jtzm                                                0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  rook                       rook-ceph-osd-*****-gwb8j    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  spark                      accelerate-test-5-a3bfb8a597e83d459193a183e17f13b5-exec-1       2 (12%)       0 (0%)      10Gi (8%)        12Gi (10%)
  spark                      accelerate-testing-1-8ed0482f3bfb3c0a83da30bb7d433dff-exec-5    2 (12%)       0 (0%)      10Gi (8%)        12Gi (10%)
  spark                      accelerate-testing-2-8cecc18bb42f31a386c6304bd63e9eba-driver    1 (6%)        0 (0%)      2Gi (1%)         2432Mi (1%)
  spark                      accelerate-testing-2-e8bd0607cc693bc8ae25cc6dc300b2c7-driver    1 (6%)        0 (0%)      2Gi (1%)         2432Mi (1%)

Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  7050m (44%)   1200m (7%)  33410Mi (27%)    45874Mi (37%)

Events:         <none>
```

Kubectl describe pod gives below message

```
Name:         accelerate-testing-2-8cecc18bb42f31a386c6304bd63e9eba-driver
Namespace:    spark
Node:         ****
Start Time:   Mon, 13 Aug 2018 16:18:34 -0400
Labels:       launch-id=k8s-submit-service-cddf45ff-0d88-4681-af85-d8ed0359ce73
              spark-app-selector=spark-63f536fd87f8457796802767922ef7d9
              spark-role=driver
Annotations:  spark-app-name=accelerate-testing-2
Status:       Pending
IP:           
Init Containers:
  spark-init:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         ****:v2.3.0
    Image ID:      
    Port:          <none>
    Args:
      init
      /etc/spark-init/spark-init.properties
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/spark-init from spark-init-properties (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from spark-token-mj86g (ro)
      /var/spark-data/spark-files from download-files-volume (rw)
      /var/spark-data/spark-jars from download-jars-volume (rw)
Containers:
  spark-kubernetes-driver:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         ******:v2.3.0
    Image ID:      
    Port:          <none>
    Args:
      driver
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      memory:  2432Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  2Gi
    Environment:
      SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY:        2g
      SPARK_DRIVER_CLASS:         com.myclass
      SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS:   (v1:status.podIP)
      SPARK_MOUNTED_CLASSPATH:    /var/spark-data/spark-jars/quantum-workflow-2.2.24.0-SNAPSHOT-assembly.jar:/var/spark-data/spark-jars/my.jar
      SPARK_MOUNTED_FILES_DIR:    /var/spark-data/spark-files
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_0:           -Dspark.kubernetes.container.image=***
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_1:           -Dspark.jars=s3a://my/my.jar,s3a://my/my1.jar
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_2:           -Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_3:           -Dspark.driver.blockManager.port=7079
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_4:           -Dspark.executor.memory=10g
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_5:           -Dspark.app.id=spark-63f536fd87f8457796802767922ef7d9
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_6:           -Dspark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_7:           -Dspark.master=k8s://https://kubernetes.default
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_8:           -Dspark.driver.host=spark-1534191513364-driver-svc.spark.svc
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_9:           -Dspark.executor.cores=2
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_10:          -Dspark.kubernetes.executor.podNamePrefix=accelerate-testing-2-8cecc18bb42f31a386c6304bd63e9eba
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_11:          -Dspark.driver.port=7078
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_12:          -Dspark.kubernetes.namespace=spark
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_13:          -Dspark.executor.memoryOverhead=2g
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_14:          -Dspark.kubernetes.initContainer.configMapName=accelerate-testing-2-8cecc18bb42f31a386c6304bd63e9eba-init-config
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_15:          -Dspark.kubernetes.initContainer.configMapKey=spark-init.properties
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_16:          -Dspark.executor.instances=10
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_17:          -Dspark.memory.fraction=0.6
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_18:          -Dspark.driver.memory=2g
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_19:          -Dspark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=accelerate-testing-2-8cecc18bb42f31a386c6304bd63e9eba-driver
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_20:          -Dspark.app.name=accelerate-testing-2
      SPARK_JAVA_OPT_21:          -Dspark.kubernetes.driver.label.launch-id=********
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from spark-token-mj86g (ro)
      /var/spark-data/spark-files from download-files-volume (rw)
      /var/spark-data/spark-jars from download-jars-volume (rw)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    False 
  Ready          False 
  PodScheduled   True 
Volumes:
  spark-init-properties:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      accelerate-testing-2-8cecc18bb42f31a386c6304bd63e9eba-init-config
    Optional:  false
  download-jars-volume:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:  
  download-files-volume:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:  
  spark-token-mj86g:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  spark-token-mj86g
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                  From                                               Message
  ----     ------          ----                 ----                                               -------
  Normal   SandboxChanged  44m (x518 over 18h)  kubelet, ****************************  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  FailedSync      19s (x540 over 18h)  kubelet, ****************************  Error syncing pod
```

I have also tried `kubectl top nodes` none of the nodes are overcommitted on the resources

Comment: Has it ever worked - is this the first submit? I wonder if `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` or `kubectl get events` might provide any more info. Possibly relevant could be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274991/kubernetes-pod-stuck-in-waiting-state or https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4891

Comment: @RyanDawson This happens only if run jobs in parallel i have updated my question with describe pod result as well

Comment: So it is working if you only submit one job, but fails if you submit several simultaneously (or near simultaneously)?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Filed an upstream ticket for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25128

Comment: @eje whats more concerning is the node has enough resources to accomodate the pods but still it says Overcommitted

Comment: There are several other SO questions that mention the `FailedSync` warning and generally boil down to some infrastructure issue (full disk on the node, buggy network driver, very slow shared filesystem).  I don't think anything in your code or deployment causes this.

Comment: @eje im still facing this issuer please lemme know if you have any suggestions here?

Comment: @shiv455, I have faced this problem before. Just restart docker in the node where the pod is created.